# How does windows load DLLs

Tags: dll, dllimport, dll-injection

I have an executable which is linked to a DLL library. This DLL is in c:\windows\system32
If I put a second DLL in the same path of the executable, this DLL should be loaded instead of the c:\windows\system32
It is very strange because it works like this for some DLLs and not for other.
I tried to copy all dlls of c:\windows\system32 in my executable path and I see with IDA (module window) that some DLLs are loaded in the executable path and others are still loaded in c:\windows\system32
I have scanned all DLLs content, thinking the path was hard coded, but I just see strings with just dll name.
So my question is: What is the rule applied by windows in order to choose which dll to load if there is multiple versions (in executable path and in c:\windows\system32)
Thanks

Comment: *Never* put DLLs in that directory, only operating system files belong there.  If you do this anyway then you'll have plenty of weirdo problems, induced by the file redirector that ensures that a 32-bit process can only see files in c:\windows\syswow64.  The OS always looks first in the directory where the EXE is stored, that's where those DLLs belong.

Comment: This is a question whose answer is irrelevant. You aren't ever going to need to know because your libraries won't be in the system folder and the system's libraries won't be in your folder.